# When I clear the app data it doesn't work anymore

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am doing an app using xamarin forms, I tested it on my celphone, then the apk is there. But when I Clear the data on android, my app doesn't open anymore...
Did someone see that?
What is the problem??

Comment: Is your app/apk built in debug or release mode?

Comment: denbug...is it normal?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is normal for `Xamarin.Android` apps built in debug mode.

If you `Clear Data` you are removing directories/files that are used for debugging:

Before clearing data:

```
.:
drwxrwx--x   2 u0_a93 u0_a93 4096 2017-09-11 21:15 cache
drwxrwx--x   2 u0_a93 u0_a93 4096 2017-09-11 21:15 code_cache
drwxrwx--x   5 u0_a93 u0_a93 4096 2017-09-11 21:24 files
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     60 2017-09-11 21:15 lib -> /data/app/com.sushihangover.GeneticCancerDNAMapper-1/lib/x86
    ./cache:
    ./code_cache:
    ./files:
        drwxrwxrwx 3 u0_a93 u0_a93 4096 2017-09-11 21:24 .__override__
        drwxr-xr-x 2 u0_a93 u0_a93 4096 2017-09-11 21:24 .config
        drwxr-xr-x 3 u0_a93 u0_a93 4096 2017-09-11 21:24 .local
        ./files/.__override__:
            drwxrwxrwx 2 u0_a93 u0_a93 4096 2017-09-11 21:24 links
        ./files/.__override__/links:
            lrwxrwxrwx 1 u0_a93 u0_a93   70 2017-09-11 21:24 libmonosgen-2.0.so -> /data/app/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime-1/lib/x86/libmonosgen-32bit-2.0.so
        ./files/.config:
        ./files/.local:
            drwxr-xr-x 2 u0_a93 u0_a93 4096 2017-09-11 21:24 share
            ./files/.local/share:
```

After clearing data:

```
.:
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root     60 2017-09-11 21:25 lib -> /data/app/com.sushihangover.GeneticCancerDNAMapper-1/lib/x86
```

This data is not needed for release builds and the `Application.DataDir` is not used by Xamarin's runtime in release builds.

Comment: Do you know How can I know the size of my apk ?
It will be that size I can see in the debug apk?
Can I have any idea about the size?
Because in my phone I can see it has 20 mb of apk, and other 15 of sd card data...do you what is this sd card data?

Comment: @JoycedeLanna A normal debug-based `.apk` is using also using the installed shared runtime libraries (`Mono.Android.DebugRuntime` & `Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_26`). The final release apk size is highly dependent upon Proguard and the Mono Linker and how you have configured those. You can get the "largest" size of the apk by just do an adhoc-based release archive and publish (to your local PC) with Proguard and the Linker tuned off. Look at the file size of the apk, now you know how large it will be, you can next start enabling Linker (SDK-Only and All) and Proguard to reduce it...