# Why clearing data of Android app prevents it from opening?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

It seems like the app rewrite the necessary files into the storage when opening it, but it doesn't load. What might cause it?
What actually happens when clearing data?

Note:
It seems like it happens only for all Xamarin apps. When clearing data apps based on Android Studio, it works just fine.

[image][image]

Comment: Is this your app? If not StackOverflow is for programming problems. If it is, show code and logcat. Also if you are using a tool like Xamarin update your tags/question.

Comment: Is this a debug or an release/ad-hoc install?

Comment: The "P.C.P" one is a debug, the "Hello World" is an ad hoc.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46167347/4984832

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Clearing data as it sounds simply just `Clear the data` of your app. So if you had logged in to the app, it will remove the credentials saved in the phone memory plus it removes the cache data stored in the phone.

Also, it removes all the permissions that the user has granted access to earlier. So, the user will now have to give all the permissions again.

Comment: I don't have any login system..